# How can I put values in a derivative function created with sympy?

Tags: python, math

```
import sympy 

def ham(): #if I use ham(5) it will give 0  
    x = sympy.Symbol("x")
    return x**3 + x**2 + 1
a = sympy.diff(ham())
print(a)
```

How can I put the value in Derivative function ?

Example :

**( x^3 + x^2 + 1 )** -- Derivative --> **( 3*x^2 + 2*x )** -- Put value **3** --> give me **33**

Thanks for support ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as the last line the following:

```
a.subs(sympy.Symbol("x"), 3)
```